Unable to verify CRL using openSSL
I have created a https CRL in both DER and PEM format, but it looks like openssl isn't even attempting to reach out to my distribution point to get the CRL. Both the int and root ca issuers are trusted on my server. I am able to curl the CRL and verify it using OpenSSL with the commands below (depending on whether it is in DER or PEM format):
openssl crl -in crlfile.pem -text -noout

OR

openssl crl -in crlfile.der -inform DER -out crlfile.pem -outform PEM
openssl crl -inform DER -in crlfile.pem -text -noout

Running on RHEL8
cat /etc/redhat-release; uname -r
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.8 (Ootpa)
4.18.0-477.36.1.el8_8.x86_64

OpenSSL Version:
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021

Error:
openssl verify -crl_check leaf.pem
C = US, L = XX, O = XXXX, CN = server.example.net
error 3 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL
error leaf.pem: verification failed

Leaf certificate:
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            03:c3:37:1a:cb:e9:1c:8f:41:0b:b6:5d:e7:da:37:9a:56:b7:c7:c3
        Signature Algorithm: sha384WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, L = XX, O = XXXX, CN = XXXX-Int-XX-GP
        Validity
            Not Before: May  1 10:02:09 2024 GMT
            Not After : Jul 30 10:12:09 2024 GMT
        Subject: C = US, L = XX, O = EXAMPLE, CN = server.example.net
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    XXXXXX
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                52:1E:5A:F0:27:EC:2B:59:C2:49:BB:44:79:55:20:2B:71:4E:E0:DE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:F9:F6:A4:D5:39:31:BB:4A:FC:69:4E:C1:FD:E9:22:52:DE:AF:BB:87

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:server.example.net
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

                Full Name:
                  URI:https://ca.xx.example.net/v1/pki/crl

    Signature Algorithm: sha384WithRSAEncryption
         75:8d:b3:4e:f9:88:90:4d:5c:77:99:b2:67:27:c9:e3:f8:b4:
         3f:f8:d9:2f:3c:14:3f:0a:e6:cd:1e:84:f3:7b:e7:72:6d:01:
         99:e3:15:f3:14:d7:3f:03:cd:9d:c4:92:e9:6c:1a:e2:db:44:
         36:af:9b:12:21:fe:61:0d:6d:14:4d:88:d5:78:37:c2:74:f5:
         ae:50:28:df:31:48:4f:db:51:db:55:1b:97:03:28:65:70:3c:
         ce:99:ba:f4:24:de:72:7f:bf:72:c8:8f:64:7e:71:6d:5f:85:
         e4:e3:b0:0f:a3:76:61:f9:b0:0c:36:7f:a5:80:6d:a0:4f:0b:
         31:cc:0a:8c:9e:83:51:15:c6:50:ca:7c:f9:06:a2:d9:aa:a9:
         63:8d:be:9f:cf:ce:d3:db:d4:61:b6:3a:fa:95:a4:2b:ba:86:
         f0:01:b1:5f:c1:15:ef:dc:f0:8e:e9:65:a8:04:0d:ef:af:3e:
         b3:6c:77:b7:6d:2c:c4:1f:11:73:47:69:15:a6:7b:ea:90:71:
         ac:ca:a6:d4:c5:7f:dc:ac:e6:16:ca:33:cd:f8:c9:51:95:a3:
         ac:9b:c6:03:d9:53:6f:83:2d:51:61:a9:f7:31:f1:66:80:ba:
         96:2b:3d:a2:57:eb:1d:9f:36:6c:d7:fb:32:c7:2e:ba:90:e3:
         20:3c:39:9e:cd:61:be:18:25:09:0d:af:bb:28:a2:3d:bb:70:
         51:d5:a0:95:bd:4a:51:de:17:3b:ad:91:8f:2a:9b:ce:a3:43:
         d7:0d:fa:66:29:92:54:1f:a5:ba:45:d0:7f:74:6d:3c:6f:fe:
         6c:88:07:0e:fa:fe:23:1c:54:f3:ae:45:6e:a0:53:35:70:58:
         da:fa:c9:34:5d:8d:6f:d9:8c:37:76:0e:29:dc:ac:14:0c:72:
         01:20:4b:f1:78:3b:0f:7f:d8:95:2c:73:b4:70:a9:1f:2d:cc:
         3f:78:4c:3c:b5:69:f9:c9:4c:1f:56:b6:24:12:6b:ba:a3:2c:
         94:78:17:a9:b0:42:85:05:17:a0:08:36:ca:51:99:13:3d:7c:
         21:41:8a:d8:bd:3f:da:b8:1b:3c:75:f3:17:71:38:77:4c:32:
         53:0e:d2:bf:17:18:a2:83:8e:25:bc:59:31:9e:49:c9:aa:9a:
         74:67:0d:c3:d4:18:b1:0a:31:ac:28:6b:15:d1:f3:45:88:5b:
         64:7d:85:09:81:2c:94:bf:92:c7:f9:cb:cd:3a:ff:78:c3:9f:
         a4:e6:47:33:3b:f7:93:ba:2b:7b:7c:0b:16:e2:b3:5d:11:6e:
         e2:9b:0f:3b:31:4d:95:10:1f:82:22:73:58:3b:80:bc:d1:10:
         bd:09:6f:b0:05:2b:59:8b

Intermediate Issuer (trusted):
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            01:9a:17:70:e8:d2:c5:a1:02:21:70:3b:61:3f:2f:2f:e1:12:08:12
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, L=XX, O=XXXX, CN=XXXX CA XX GP
        Validity
            Not Before: May  1 08:03:21 2024 GMT
            Not After : Apr 30 08:03:51 2029 GMT
        Subject: C=US, L=XX, O=XXXX, CN=XXXX-Int-XX-GP
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    XXXXX
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                F9:F6:A4:D5:39:31:BB:4A:FC:69:4E:C1:FD:E9:22:52:DE:AF:BB:87
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:9D:F5:D6:A3:1E:EB:D8:2D:E0:64:C3:59:94:AD:A1:C4:DA:73:91:A9

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:server.xx.example.net
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         17:dc:6f:5e:9c:1c:2b:51:ed:a3:9f:73:a7:cb:45:9c:c4:68:
         e2:88:d4:eb:1c:a0:a3:cc:5a:bb:7b:4e:7b:b8:c5:26:08:35:
         54:57:d7:86:94:8d:71:a7:fd:b9:76:04:31:ac:75:e0:c8:11:
         23:fc:09:85:06:08:9e:a7:fd:da:a7:68:18:87:30:a9:96:a3:
         cf:ec:b2:a3:75:77:a9:77:0c:af:1b:df:34:98:9c:47:a4:96:
         87:c4:24:38:b0:09:4d:f8:85:d5:6c:b8:f7:33:26:45:af:bb:
         b1:12:cc:7b:a4:7a:bf:b7:a4:bd:2e:81:6d:bc:38:d6:f0:86:
         4e:09:f1:69:d3:14:4e:c0:c6:bc:14:a5:31:69:0a:59:dd:46:
         2a:73:eb:b7:23:c4:b2:92:97:96:9e:f1:60:4b:bc:34:07:17:
         ef:0d:dc:53:24:39:e4:95:75:00:7f:0f:d2:16:d0:ff:54:81:
         4b:17:30:1a:a8:9f:70:ca:70:ed:9f:ba:f6:27:f3:d8:81:08:
         ac:b4:40:c5:cd:1f:39:64:65:4f:c9:30:df:59:af:b3:36:c0:
         0c:0f:85:48:de:98:62:17:94:8b:ff:f4:b4:f4:84:78:bf:b3:
         4d:6d:48:57:30:0e:23:c9:48:eb:1b:27:f0:c5:a7:a1:84:1a:
         95:89:43:e3:d5:af:03:63:bc:68:c6:fa:2c:fd:ec:57:12:9a:
         5b:cf:27:dd:e4:07:94:11:29:ff:30:ce:e3:47:65:6c:e3:7f:
         d9:76:d0:2c:57:d2:d0:13:3f:08:e7:f5:40:4e:7c:8b:ab:cc:
         a1:05:ae:b1:3d:6c:81:27:0e:1b:3f:8f:38:3f:22:51:1e:8e:
         f5:c4:f9:aa:b7:47:5f:49:d2:27:91:3f:44:6f:a3:25:96:80:
         13:db:ea:f1:cf:d3:c8:3e:6e:b9:db:54:93:51:aa:23:b7:9c:
         5d:f5:54:ab:2e:b6:b0:0a:fa:7c:75:d1:ca:01:7b:0f:a5:2b:
         07:3e:46:b4:f6:e9:fe:7d:f6:7a:58:e5:33:79:4b:88:a3:30:
         38:98:1f:ca:2e:f1:9b:96:9c:23:9a:36:87:eb:bf:7a:37:c0:
         64:27:cc:2e:69:b0:91:f4:ca:a8:9d:75:2a:60:3a:d5:78:d8:
         da:fa:20:d6:e7:8e:64:1c:f9:5c:ab:5e:87:f7:52:0b:e8:db:
         20:f1:73:9c:99:68:cd:7e:50:75:4c:3f:d9:0a:aa:2a:51:c9:
         d0:9e:b4:e7:30:2f:a5:f4:9d:54:d6:59:43:78:b9:8b:a2:f9:
         15:2e:74:19:ef:ec:1d:72:f3:35:2a:ae:71:f7:fd:13:23:08:
         e0:b6:02:da:25:31:67:22

Root Issuer (trusted):
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            08:6d:c8:33:27:20:14:a9:02:c9:87:ed:8a:43:e9:61:f3:99:64:69
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, L=XX, O=XXXX, CN=XXXX CA XX GP
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar  7 15:47:06 2024 GMT
            Not After : Mar  5 15:47:35 2034 GMT
        Subject: C=US, L=XX, O=XXXX, CN=XXXX CA XX GP
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    XXXX
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                9D:F5:D6:A3:1E:EB:D8:2D:E0:64:C3:59:94:AD:A1:C4:DA:73:91:A9
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:9D:F5:D6:A3:1E:EB:D8:2D:E0:64:C3:59:94:AD:A1:C4:DA:73:91:A9

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         8e:53:15:3b:3e:f2:63:b9:77:c9:c7:2c:b7:4b:e9:5c:6a:07:
         34:e9:53:d8:b6:94:e0:da:0e:bf:80:82:31:b4:0a:5b:67:e6:
         3d:eb:7f:d6:d9:8d:af:1f:1d:81:fe:3f:6f:20:cf:67:ba:33:
         5e:35:b0:cd:d1:1f:5c:28:40:5c:a1:e4:2c:e8:4f:93:e1:5d:
         59:4b:c1:00:d9:19:c5:32:ee:67:46:95:04:7e:ba:15:ee:8a:
         39:b6:0a:89:64:53:b9:f0:7b:13:94:31:99:1a:d4:40:55:ca:
         c6:f4:c2:65:85:42:4b:0a:76:7d:98:8c:c3:68:15:ec:d4:28:
         15:24:b9:bc:ed:04:b7:ba:f7:86:6a:1d:62:c9:75:ab:15:d8:
         7d:96:80:df:2c:09:43:3b:be:b1:80:dd:aa:73:32:f9:27:c1:
         a1:44:fa:81:bc:06:29:bd:f9:35:94:16:5a:02:17:71:ae:17:
         60:d6:ce:7a:a6:1d:8f:89:52:19:95:64:6d:52:98:52:98:99:
         cf:cb:a9:bd:70:5f:16:8a:71:4f:3e:65:d0:7b:91:fe:d0:73:
         48:53:36:c8:66:43:49:e3:a1:6a:38:2c:af:9e:dd:32:94:a5:
         df:d9:8c:a8:a9:8c:85:78:d6:a3:db:2d:58:eb:99:d4:6b:e6:
         63:a5:c1:fa:45:85:64:ec:91:b3:9c:05:e1:a2:df:68:10:32:
         57:d3:7e:f1:f5:d7:c4:6d:72:85:e7:93:2e:a2:77:81:35:2c:
         1c:02:3c:50:01:d3:05:98:76:9a:92:e1:7e:06:86:7d:22:e4:
         5e:03:37:c6:72:d7:1a:f3:5b:60:59:76:b2:e4:44:46:c0:92:
         9c:96:22:fb:60:5d:9f:ce:91:66:5e:17:d0:c7:8f:7f:1b:79:
         6b:9a:7d:50:fa:0a:a8:98:d5:ad:ab:a0:03:57:ca:c3:80:2e:
         71:3e:41:86:3d:94:4d:c3:20:0e:9c:52:e1:11:9e:86:a5:d5:
         25:0d:19:9c:ad:a3:8f:41:0c:e0:66:44:51:4a:8b:09:22:37:
         ef:72:b6:e2:f6:0a:b5:0b:88:0b:74:77:98:2b:cd:ac:e5:4a:
         e5:e7:a9:73:6c:21:fd:b0:2c:f2:92:a4:5d:1f:7b:24:e2:84:
         54:12:39:6a:df:cc:3c:55:45:81:53:46:7c:47:1d:1a:70:57:
         54:13:e9:81:bd:7a:83:eb:82:8c:01:68:f7:bd:0a:ff:14:17:
         03:42:51:7c:2f:53:48:66:27:9b:a2:b8:6e:81:27:2d:87:64:
         e4:83:d3:24:2e:17:47:6b:fa:53:be:60:63:8b:91:83:fe:48:
         4e:7d:98:f4:c5:48:a9:98

My CRL:
Certificate Revocation List (CRL):
        Version 2 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, L = XX, O = XXXX, CN = XXXX-Int-XX-GP
        Last Update: May  1 08:03:51 2024 GMT
        Next Update: May  8 08:03:51 2024 GMT
        CRL extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:F9:F6:A4:D5:39:31:BB:4A:FC:69:4E:C1:FD:E9:22:52:DE:AF:BB:87

            X509v3 CRL Number:
                1
No Revoked Certificates.
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         51:ca:55:9e:25:2c:fa:3b:6f:72:6b:23:c7:28:89:c4:de:8e:
         9a:f6:d3:90:0f:07:fb:a5:ca:55:c0:2a:f9:52:b8:a5:cf:4d:
         db:a8:f4:62:c9:f2:f5:0b:a2:79:0b:f8:d7:cf:ca:98:2e:bd:
         48:e4:41:1f:6b:74:5a:80:11:05:cb:5c:0e:18:1f:03:cc:b7:
         95:60:03:a8:fa:c2:a2:93:73:60:9d:1b:5f:43:c6:a4:05:00:
         da:a4:63:87:dd:ea:00:c8:4f:f3:0a:b6:2a:6d:28:c2:e9:7d:
         b4:3c:12:d8:2b:a5:ec:57:23:bb:2a:de:6a:03:01:a5:63:e0:
         98:73:27:11:e1:4d:aa:23:45:6b:9d:25:76:6e:ed:76:de:63:
         4a:3c:c0:44:88:72:ef:04:b6:5d:5a:21:13:a4:d4:05:92:30:
         e6:77:7d:47:7f:f4:ad:f6:63:60:a1:d0:21:5c:78:13:90:6b:
         46:a0:99:50:d0:52:eb:c8:8d:8a:40:e8:3f:63:7f:b3:00:7e:
         ef:92:b1:57:92:51:9a:c3:c6:18:0f:50:e7:73:7e:f9:1c:db:
         6b:cc:3c:56:86:55:10:39:8d:e4:50:79:d1:19:2d:a9:38:70:
         26:ab:79:5a:99:15:b2:f7:d5:49:f7:13:93:30:2e:59:65:4d:
         00:45:ef:e3:2d:ce:b7:30:62:c8:80:4b:d7:23:b1:af:72:99:
         25:f7:74:60:db:f3:55:36:75:be:02:f7:44:28:3d:a9:91:dd:
         fb:84:fd:30:c0:5d:f8:5f:bc:88:c2:b9:c8:86:1c:a0:91:44:
         df:79:72:aa:0b:04:80:44:8e:4b:97:53:98:a8:f8:51:38:28:
         df:c6:f2:5f:09:de:f8:23:fe:6b:fa:a1:e8:78:25:26:21:bb:
         63:29:c2:38:c4:b4:25:81:05:85:9d:3f:4b:ab:24:23:9a:3d:
         38:aa:41:78:2d:93:31:63:0c:8c:3d:10:cd:a7:1a:56:16:04:
         85:db:cb:16:08:e5:0d:60:b0:4d:8c:4d:ad:19:62:ea:5f:5f:
         f6:7a:d6:e5:7f:03:6b:cc:e0:a8:d3:37:6d:3f:58:bc:75:7f:
         47:ce:6f:d1:52:81:c0:21:86:3c:f0:2b:e0:39:c6:c6:dc:60:
         27:db:91:37:db:3b:92:72:b4:71:23:16:91:a6:57:0a:78:1b:
         1e:c6:62:72:47:aa:2a:3e:d6:ef:41:18:33:68:be:2e:0e:68:
         5a:a6:81:11:00:0f:8b:9d:6b:7e:2f:f8:74:8c:db:07:48:4a:
         3b:cb:e5:8c:00:c5:d7:35:6a:cb:75:30:20:fe:b8:83:15:b2:
         7f:53:84:17:64:2e:82:e8

Strace:
read(3, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIE"..., 4096) = 1781
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3561, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3561, ...}) = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 3561
lseek(3, -2269, SEEK_CUR)               = 1292
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2269
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/etc/pki/tls/certs/fcf31071.r0", 0x7fff7a6bf0c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "error 3 at 0 depth lookup: unabl"..., 57error 3 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL
) = 57


Why you host CRLs behind HTTPS? It should be served over plain text HTTP.

Purely for testing here! The whole chain is trusted in this case. Got confirmation about the cause of the issue from the openssl maintainers. Will add here shortly

It appears the functionality I was trying to test is not supported. From the OpenSSL maintainers on Github:
I should have written that before - OpenSSL by itself does not support fetching the CRLs from any remote locations. It needs to be implemented by the application as @petrovr wrote above.

See full thread with nmroe details here
